# Can I tether my iPhone 4S onto WiFi on my computer through USB?

Tags: wifi

I'm having trouble resolving issues I have on my iPhone 4S with regard to WiFi. It is unable to scan for networks. I live in Sri Lanka and technical support for iPhones is very limited. I was wondering if in case I'm unable to solve it, will I be able to tether my phone to the WiFi on the laptop? That is, use WiFi on my iPhone through my computer?